# Render Draft.js Html into a div tag with proper markup?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, draftjs

I am looking at using [draft.js](https://draftjs.org/) and I am wondering how I can have an editor and while someone types the results would be shown as html but with the actual **markup** (ie if I do bold, the output shows bold).

I am having trouble getting this to work. I tried `dangerouslySetInnerHTML` but that did not seem to work.

```
  <div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: this.state.editorContentHtml }}></div>


import React from "react";
import { Editor, EditorState } from "draft-js";
import { stateToHTML } from "draft-js-export-html";

class ExampleEditor1 extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { editorState: EditorState.createEmpty() };
    this.onChange = editorState => {
      this.setState({
        editorState,
        editorContentHtml: stateToHTML(editorState.getCurrentContent())
      });
    };
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <div className="editor-container" style={{ border: "1px solid #000" }}>
          <Editor
            editorState={this.state.editorState}
            onChange={this.onChange}
          />
        </div>
        <h4>Editor content as HTML</h4>
        <div>{this.state.editorContentHtml}</div>

      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default ExampleEditor1;
```

Answer (score 0):

I haven't used `draft-js-export-html` package yet & I'm lazy. So I'm not pointing out the reason why your code didn't work.

But the following code should do the task:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Editor, EditorState } from 'draft-js';

const styles = {
  editor: {
    border: "1px solid gray",
    display: "block",
    minHeight: "15em"
  }
};

class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      editorState: EditorState.createEmpty(),
      preview: null
    };

    this.onChange = editorState => this.setState({
      editorState,
      preview: editorState.getCurrentContent().getPlainText()
    });

    this.setEditor = ref => {
      this.editor = ref;
    };
    this.focusEditor = () => {
      if (this.editor) {
        this.editor.focus();
      }
    };
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <React.Fragment>
        <div style={styles.editor} onClick={this.focusEditor}>
          <Editor
            ref={this.setEditor}
            editorState={this.state.editorState}
            onChange={this.onChange}
          />
        </div>
        <div
          style={{ minHeight: "200px" }}
          dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: this.state.preview }}
        />
      </React.Fragment>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```